# Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type(with well defined structs) in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dereference

I know there are at least 10 questions already about this, but they all point to something I am not doing.

In a header file I have...

```
typedef struct Node {
   struct Node *next;
   struct pgmap page;
} Node;

typedef struct linkedlist {
struct Node *head_ptr;
struct Node *tail_ptr;
} LList;
```

In my c file I have

```
struct LList mainList;

int main()
{
    struct LList *root;
    root = &mainList;
    root->head_ptr = NULL;
    root->tail_ptr = NULL;
    ...
}
```

On the root-> lines I get the dereferencing ptr... error. All the threads already on here point to a problem where people accidentally create anonymous structs, such as

```
typedef struct{
    int a;
}; monkey
```

instead of

```
typedef struct monkey{
    int a;
}; monkey
```

So what am I missing????

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no type called "`struct LList`".  The code "`typedef struct linkedlist { ... } LList;`" creates two type names: one is `struct linkedlist`, and the other is just `LList` (without "`struct`").  You thus need to change "`struct LList`" to "`LList`."

Comment: OMG, as you can tell, C noob up in here. Now I don't know if I like typedef'ing a struct. Kind of nice using sublime and having "struct" as it's own highlighted color. Thank you so much.